# Replacing an InputBox with a Userform (combobox)?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

Forgive my noob-ery. Assistance greatly appreciated!!!!

Purpose of macro: Fill in form in Microsoft Word with text originating in an Excel workbook from a specified worksheet.

My problem: Selecting said worksheet to draw that information from and integrating result into my code. Using an InputBox for now but would like to replace said InputBox with a UserForm with a ComboBox- giving pre-set choice for worksheet names (these never change).

I've created the UserForm with the choices. How do I get my code to initialize it? And how do I get my code to use the result from the ComboBox?

```
Sub Ooopsie()
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim exSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strSheetName As String
Dim strDefaultText As String

strDefaultText = "sheet name here"

strSheetName = InputBox( _
Prompt:="The sheet name is?", _
Title:="Sheet Name?", _
Default:=strDefaultText _
)

If strSheetName = strDefaultText Or strSheetName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path to worksheet")


ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Blah: " & exWb.Sheets(strSheetName).Cells(3, 3)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(5).Cells(1).Range.Text = "blah blah : " & Chr(11) & "blah: " & exWb.Sheets(strSheetName).Cells(3, 1)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(6).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Date de réception : " & Chr(11) & "Date Received : " & exWb.Sheets(strSheetName).Cells(3, 2)
 ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(7).Cells(1).Range.Text = "blah d : " & Chr(11) & "Deadline: " & exWb.Sheets(strSheetName).Cells(3, 4)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the `Box` method in your code? That's not built-in VBA. What's the name of your UserForm? What's the name of the Combobox control?

Comment: What's the form called? `New` it up and call its `Show` method... none of that code seems relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I refined your code some.  This should get you started. I reworked it to make it easier for you to see what's going on.  Instead of opening an existing workbook I create a new workbook.  I left the Inputbox in there with some error handling so you get an idea of what you should do. The code now right from the MS Word table to Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xlApp, xlWB, xlWS
    Dim strSheetName As String, strDefaultText As String
    Dim tbl As Table

    strDefaultText = "Sheet1"
    strSheetName = InputBox( _
                   Prompt:="The sheet name is?", _
                   Title:="Sheet Name?", _
                   Default:=strDefaultText)

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlWS = xlWB.WorkSheets(strSheetName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet [" & strSheetName & " Not Found", vbCritical, "Action Cancelled"
        xlWB.Close False
        xlApp.Quit
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    xlApp.Visible = True

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        xlWS.Cells(3, 3) = tbl.Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.Text
        xlWS.Cells(3, 1) = tbl.Rows(5).Cells(1).Range.Text
        xlWS.Cells(3, 2) = tbl.Rows(6).Cells(1).Range.Text
        xlWS.Cells(3, 4) = tbl.Rows(7).Cells(1).Range.Text
    End If

    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

It is worth noting that you can't instantiate Excel from MS Word like this without a reference to the Microsoft Excel 12.0 I think is?

> ```
> Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
> ```

Use this instead

> ```
> Dim objExcel as Variant
> Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> ```

I know that this is not a chat forum but I am open to opinions and advice.  I am only a hobbist after all.

**Update** here is how one way add items to a combobox

```
For Each xlSheet In xlWB.Worksheets
    ComboBox1.AddItem xlSheet.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

So you've created a form called `UserForm1`.

You can display it as a modal dialog using the *default instance*:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModal
```

But a better practice would be to *instantiate it* instead - forms are objects after all, so you can `New` them up like any other class module:

```
Dim view As UserForm1
Set view = New UserForm1
view.Show vbModal
```

You can add *properties* to your form's *code-behind* to expose values the calling code can use:

```
Public Property Get SheetName() As String
    SheetName = ComboBox1.Text
End Property
```

So you can now write a function that does this:

```
Private Function GetSheetName() As String
    Dim view As UserForm1
    Set view = New UserForm1
    view.Show vbModal
    GetSheetName = view.SheetName
End Function
```

Now you can replace your `InputBox` call with a call to this `GetSheetName` function!

Of course you'll want to handle the case where the user cancels out of the form, but that's beyond the scope of this question, and... it's been asked on this site already, just search and you'll find!

Comment: Didn't test it, no. It's illustrative anyway, the point holds. Edit it into working code if you like, I didn't provide this snippet to be copy-pasta'd and used as-is...

Comment: My apologies it did work in Excel.  I still don't see the advantage of doing this. But all I have is assumptions on how Applications try on optimize.

Comment: What is this "this" anyway? Working with object instances? Addig model properties to the form object? I didn't want to throw an MVP pattern at the OP here, but then these *model* properties could easily be extracted into their own class, to better *separate concerns*. Which part violates any best-practice?

Comment: Honestly I have no right to question you.  You do have a 10 k + rep.  Again I apologize.

Comment: OP here - @Mat'sMug thanks for the illustrative post. I appreciate it. I'm here to learn and your post is helping me to do that!